# Display a dynamically updated quantity BUT store the older versions

Tags: database, django-models, database-design

I'm working on a web application for a farmer, a permacultor to be more precise. It implies that he's handling various seeds and plants. The purpose of the application is to store in database data regarding his garden. Once enough data are gathered, the application is to provide a frame to analyze data.

For now I'm developping the first fonctionality : store data in database and display them on webpages.

Let's focus on the main topic of this question.

The garden has several fields. A field can contain several plants. Plants can have several state throught time (seed, plant, flower, harvestable).

When a plant reach a state, we need to store specific information :

- the state
- the date when state was observed (and other time-related data)
- the quantity (from seed state to flower state, we can have loss for many reasons)

So far so good, nothing fancy.

**NOW a plant can grow on a field until a specitifc state then be planted into another field until its harvesting.**

For instance, 12 carrots that are growing in tray n°3 from the seed to germination state.

At germination state, 2 carrots didn't make it. The farmer now intend to resume the growing of his carrots not in tray n°3 but in field n°1

In model, let's say "state_plant_table" you have 2 entries :

carrots - 12 - seeds - tray n°3
carrots - 10 - germ - field n°1

You might see it coming.

Let's say now that... there isn't enough room in field n°1 for the 10 carrots, only 8 can fit. So he just put the 2 left in the field aside - field n°2.

We now have
carrots - 12 - seeds - tray n°3
carrots - 8 - germ - field n°1
carrots - 2 - germ - field n°2

**NOW, on display we would show HTML table for each fields, trays or w/e. When you click on a field you have the detail of every plants rooted in it.**

For field n°1 we would have :
carrots - 8

For field n°2 we would have :
carrots - 2

And, unfortunately, for tray n°3, we would have :
carrots - 12
But we should have 0 (if 0 => exclude from display of course).

**I'm struggling with the theorical design of my process right now... any tips, hints, suggestions are welcome !**

I have thought about a "parent" quantity and a "child" quantity where the initial quantity would be store in "plant_table" as "parent" quantity and "children" quantity would be stored in "state_plant_table" - the quantity is more linked to a state in which it's being observed than the plant itself.

I feel like this is the right way, but I don't manage to push the reasoning to its end either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasoning with "parent" and "children" was one of the correct approach.

There are actually 3 natures of quantity to store :

- quantity of plants observed at a certain state (quantite_etat)
- quantity of plants actually in the field (quantite)
- quantity of plants from the same parent (quantite_lot)

```
models.py

class EtatLot(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    id_lot = models.ForeignKey('Lot', on_delete = models.PROTECT, verbose_name = 'Lot', related_name = 'lot_parent', null = True, blank = True)
    etat = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'État', max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    quantite = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name = 'Quantité', null = True, blank = True)
    quantite_etat = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name = 'Quantité relatée', null = True, blank = True)

class Lot(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    quantite_lot = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name = 'Quantité', null = True, blank = True)
```

The quantity displayed is the one from quantite. The quantity used to analyze data is the one from quantite_etat.

**Example**

Let's say we have 12 cauliflower on field n°1 and the farmer want to plant 10 of them on field n°2.

Within database we have :

```
Lot table
id : 1   quantite_lot : 12


EtatLot table
id : 1   id_lot : 1   etat : Seed   quantite : 12   quantite_etat : 12
id : 2   id_lot : 1   etat : Germ   quantite : 12   quantite_etat : 12
```

At the end of operations, we should have this :

```
Lot table
id : 1   quantite_lot : 2


EtatLot table
id : 1   id_lot : 1   etat : Seed   quantite : 12   quantite_etat : 12   field : fieldn°1
id : 2   id_lot : 1   etat : Germ   quantite :  2   quantite_etat : 12   field : fieldn°1
id : 3   id_lot : 1   etat : Plan   quantite : 10   quantite_etat : 10   field : fieldn°2
```

For this operation, quantite_lot is irrelevant. However I store it in order to do some stock check : you cannot plant more plants that you have.

This is how I achieved to the table above :

- get quantity from the last child of lot_parent (quantite)
- update this value with the difference between it and the value added by the farmer in the form, update the value from quantite_lot in the parent as well
- store the value of the form in quantite and quantite_etat of the entry that is about to be added in the database